# How to reference a view inside of its own closure in Swift?

Tags: swift, closures

I have this closure defined in a UIView subclass:

```
var viewAction: (() -> Void)?
```

which is invoked like this when a button is pressed:

```
self.viewAction?()
```

In the view controller that creates the view I have this:

```
self.currentView?.viewAction = { [weak self] in
        self?.fling(view: (self?.currentView)!, velocity: CGPoint(x: 0, y: -100))
    }

func fling(view: MyView, velocity: CGPoint) {
...
}
```

Although it works, this code makes me throw up in my mouth a little. Is there a better way to call the `fling` function with `self.currentView` from inside the closure?

Comment: Can't you use the 'currentView' inside the fling() function without passing it an argument.? do the fling fn will be func fling(velocity: CGPoint) {}

Comment: @jpulikkottil I could, yes. But I'm still curious as to how to do this from within a closure.

Answer (score 0):

The required behavior could be better achieved if you inherited from `UIControl` instead of `UIView` for the `MyView` implementation. this will make it easier to detect actions by simply using `func addTarget(_ target: Any?, action: Selector, for controlEvents: UIControl.Event)`

But if for some limitation you have then here is my answer:

In the closure you don't really need self so we can replace it with weak currentView and unless you need self then you don't have to write it

so it will be something like:

```
currentView.viewAction = { [weak currentView] in

    guard let view = currentView else { return }

    self.fling(view: view, velocity: CGPoint(x: 0, y: -100))
}
```

if you still want to improve it then you can move the fling function to be in the subclass of the view

```
class MyView: UIControl {

    var viewAction: (() -> Void)?

    func fling(in frame: CGRect, velocity: CGPoint) {

    }
}

let someFrame: CGRect = currentView.frame

currentView.viewAction = { [weak currentView] in

    let velocity = CGPoint(x: 0, y: -100)

    currentView?.fling(in: someFrame, velocity: velocity)
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I actually do need "self" though. Is it possible to capture weak versions of both "self" and "currentView" in the closure?

Comment: but the view is referenced in self so it should be enough to mark self as weak but anyway just incase you need it for later just separate them by a comma `[weak self, weak currentView] in ....`